# Stop Scrollbar from resizing

Tags: excel, resize, scrollbar, vba

My VBA-Code has a little beauty mistake, that I'd like to correct.
What my code is doing is that on click some columns of a sheet are being hidden and others being shown.
The thing is that while those columns are changing so is the scrollbar. It seems resizing a few times, until the process is completed.

Is there a way to stop that?

Here is a little example of my code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("MySheet").Range("B:F").Columns.Hidden = True
Sheets("MySheet").Range("H:M").Columns.Hidden = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Of course I've already searched the Internet and Stackoverflow for solutions, but nothing worked as I wanted.

Greetings,
Frame

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this:

```
With ActiveWindow 
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False 'True 
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False 'True 
End With
```

It would simply hide it. Concerning resizing, I think that you cannot change it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! I've tried it and it works as you've told and is already way better than the bar moving around.
If there are not going to be any better solutions then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Frame - theoretically, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` should stop the ScreenUpdating and thus you should not be able to see the resizing.

Comment: @ Vityata - unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: @Frame - probably you are doing the resizing outside the `.ScreenUpdating`?

Comment: @ Vityata - no, I'm not. I was checking that several times, before posting the question